# C# simulating onclick in webbrowser

Tags: c#, events, browser, onclick, simulate

I studied similar questions, but didn't find a working solution.

So, the question is how to invoke/run an onclick in webbrowser.

If the code is like this:

```
<div class="fl_r">
<div class="delete_post">
<div id="delete_post-23304691_11" onclick="wall.deletePost('-23304691_11', '62c2b8dca377d231af');" onmouseover="wall.activeDeletePost('-23304691_11', 'Удалить запись')" onmouseout="wall.deactiveDeletePost('-23304691_11')"></div>
```

I use:

```
HtmlElement el = webBrowser1.Document.All["delete_post-23304691_11"];
el.InvokeMember("onclick");
```

And it works perfectly.

But i also have other code:

```
<div class="info_footer">
<span class="fl_r actions" id="actions-23304691_12"><a onclick="wall.deletePost('-23304691_12', '58ddeb8beaaceb4f2c');">Delete</a></span>
today at 0:52 
</div>
```

And the previous variant is not working here.
How do I invoke that onlick?

Answer (score 2):

The onclick is assigned to a, not span, this should work..

```
HtmlElement el = webBrowser1.Document.All["actions-23304691_12"].Children[0];
el.InvokeMember("onclick");
```

You can also give the a tag a unique id and invoke that instead (better approach IMHO).